# call zsh function from Powershell - in mac terminal

Tags: powershell, zsh

I have a simple function in `~/.zshrc`

zshrc:

```
function someThing() {}
```

And i now I want to call this function from Powershel, how do you do that?

I tried

Powershell:

```
Test-Zshrc-Function() {
 someThing
 # and
 -ScriptBlock ${function:someThing} -ArgumentList "arg one"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll play.  This is really a question for zsh.  Run command and interactive.  The function name is case sensitive.  In powershell, you would define the function in $profile.

```
zsh -ci someThing
```